# No Method Error editing Shopify metafield data with ruby on rails via a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, shopify, nomethoderror

As part of a customisation I'm doing for a Shopify site, I'm trying to write a tool that allows  only a specific metafield to be edited.

On the index page, I'll be listing various collections, products, pages and blog articles which are associated with a specific metafield I want the user to be able to edit via a form.

... for the life of me, I just can't see what I've missed!!  Any help in resolving this is greatly appreciated :)

So ... here we go!  When the user clicks 'edit' (which should take them to a form to edit the particular metafield for that collection, product, page or blog article), I'm getting this error in the browser :

```
NoMethodError in Metafields#edit

Showing /Users/james/code/test-app/app/views/metafields/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `shopify_api_metafield_path' for #<#<Class:0x007facf51992a0>:0x007facf520fec8>

Extracted source (around line #1):
1: <%= form_for(@metafield) do |f| %>
```

The model "metafield.rb" looks like this:

```
class Metafield < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :namespace, :key, :value, :value_type, :description, :id
end
```

The controller "metafields_controller.rb" has the following method defined:

```
  # GET /metafields/1/edit
  def edit
    @metafield = ShopifyAPI::Metafield.find(params[:id])
  end
```

The file "/views/metafields/index.html.erb" looks like this:

```
<h1>Listing metafields</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Namespace</th>
    <th>Key</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Value type</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @metafields.each do |metafield| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= metafield.namespace %></td>
    <td><%= metafield.key %></td>
    <td><%= metafield.value %></td>
    <td><%= metafield.value_type %></td>
    <td><%= metafield.description %></td>
    <td><%= metafield.id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_metafield_path(metafield) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

The file "/views/metafields/edit.html.erb" looks like this:

```
<h1>Editing metafield</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', metafields_path %>
```

The file "/views/metafields/_form.html.erb" looks like this (of which, apparently, line #1 is throwing the error...):

```
<%= form_for(@metafield) do |f| %>
  <% if @metafield.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@metafield.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this metafield from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @metafield.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :namespace %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :namespace %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :key %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :key %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :value %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :value %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :value_type %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :value_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It`s not a good idea to nest forms in view partials as you do it in _form.html.erb.

```
<%= form_for(@metafield) do |f| %>
  <% if @metafield.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@metafield.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this metafield from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @metafield.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

You can try to use this helper:

```
<%= error_messages_for 'metafield' %>
```

instead of using `form_for()` helper.

**UPDATE**

If you wish to use `form_for()` helper it will be correct to define your Metafield model this way:

```
class ShopifyAPI::Metafield < ActiveRecord::Base
{
}
```

Since the `form_for()` helper tries to figure out a path to the view that will be rendered on the form submission. This path is returned by `shopify_api_metafield_path()` helper which is undefined method from the error message.

Regarding `error_messages_for()` helper, it will not be translated into HTML form tag and can be used inside a view partial without nesting HTML forms. See more [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/ActiveRecordHelper/error_messages_for)

Comment: Thanks niebelung. I'm a ruby newb so not familiar with 'error_messages_for'.  Could you be more specific or send some more info. on how I could use the 'error_messages_for' helper instead of form_for() helper?  I thought that using form_for() was the 'correct' ruby practice as this was all generated using the standard ruby scaffold commands.

Comment: You surely can use form_for() if you wish, but you have to remember that it is invalid to render one form inside another one (you have already rendered a form in your `edit.html.erb` view). If you still would like to use form_for() helper, try to put it in your edit view above your `<%= render 'form' %>` tag.

Comment: I've been playing around with the suggestions you have made over the last week including entirely rebuilding the app (in case it's was some other thing that had impacted this) ... and ... to no avail :/  When I try updating the model metafield.rb with the suggestion, I get the following: "TypeError in MetafieldsController#edit

superclass mismatch for class Metafield"